# How do I backup scheduled tasks in Windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

"once" I did backup my scheduled tasks by xcopy'ing %winDir%\Tasks\*.job

However this does not seem to work in Server 2008. 
How do I backub my scheduled tasks using xcopy/7zip/winrar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /XML parameter of the [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(VS.85).aspx) to create a file that is importable.

Comment: Just to be clear: `schtasks /Query /XML ONE>d:\backup\Tasks\schedtasksBackup.xml`